# Error checking without coding for every procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

We have several large and small Access databases that support users across the state. Recently, I've been trying to add error checking into these datasbases since many where orginally created without it. However, some of these databases have a lot of functions and adding error checking to each one seems overly tedious.

I basically just want the database to send me an email with a description of the error and object/function on which it occurred. Is there an easier way to do this than to add error checking to each function?

Comment: So there's 2 parts to your question. The error capturing, and the email piece. I think your question should focus on one. (You can send an email with all the correct information once you have it captured. Let's work on that first.)

Comment: This also poses another problem. Are all of the databases using the same front end? or back end? Are you going to redistribute new front ends to every user once you have completed this error handling, or are you going into each user's copy and making the changes?

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly an answer (or, should I say, not the answer you want), my response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279330/how-to-diagnose-ms-access-crashes/17298144#17298144) holds true in this case as well.  In either case, I don't think you can just throw some generic function into your code, or do so without editing every pre-existing function.  If proper error trapping is built into your application, you never have to worry about it.