# Printing a userform using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to print my userform.

**Code:**

```
Forms("frm_manager_stats_NEW").Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
DoCmd.PrintOut , 1, 1, acLow, 1, False
```

**I have also tried these lines of code:**

```
DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll
```

and

```
DoCmd.PrintOut
```

**The Error:**
When I press the command button to run the code Access debugs and gives me the option to close or debug, regardless which I press the application then closes.

What is happening?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No error - It just hit the application debug saying the application has stopped responding, then the whole application closes

Comment: Try adding 'acPages' after dcmd.printout and before the first comma. also make sure the form is loaded and active.

Comment: didn't work - The printing form pops up so it must start the process but then stops working

Comment: Would is be caused if I had a tab control object on my userform?

Comment: I'd say this falls in the _unexpected crashes_ category. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897483/7296893), and walk through the steps outlined there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to first open your form in Print Preview mode and then print it out (like i have done it in one
of my projects).

Please do the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourUserFormName", acPreview
If Screen.ActiveForm.Name = "YourUserFormName" Then
DoCmd.PrintOut
End If
```

Try this and hopefully it will work for you like it worked for me.

Comment: That also doesn't work for some reason. strange isn't it