# MS Access quits on errors

Tags: ms-access, vba

When encountering an error in the VBA code I am presented with two options: End or Debug. Now - perhaps after a company-wide upgrade to W10 - I experience that pressing "End" shuts down the program and pressing "debug" brings me to the code editor, but when I stop execution to correct the error, the program shuts down.

Is this new behavior a part of some security group policy?

Also, it seems as if Setwarnings is true, the code execution is simply suspended with no messagebox when encounting an error.

Comment: I would look in your event viewer in the application log as this is not standard behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose MS access crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279330/how-to-diagnose-ms-access-crashes) (I'd say these crashes fall into the _unexpected crashes_ category)

Comment: A screenshot of this "End or Debug" message could be helpful. Can you add one to your question?

Comment: How are you executing your VBA code? Are you perhaps evaluating a VBA function from a macro which then Quits Access?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions. Especially that this is not a standard behavior. That led me to some findings:
1) No "Use Acces Special Keys" turns off error handling.
2) Using "frmInactiveShutDown v2.3 for MS Access from Peter's Software" (peterssoftware.com) causes the problem.
3) I had scripted me from using frmInactiveShutDown based on my network user name so I never noticed.
4) A major change in our network environment gave me another user name and I am/was thus subjected to frmInactiveShutDown.

I will refrain from trying to solve the problem in frmInactiveShutDown.