# Is it possible to run ms access in debug mode

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have some issue while application is starting, it does not give any errors and window completely with no control. Here is screenshot.
So my question is, can I somehow turn on debug mode and see what's happened?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no hidden *debug mode*, or anything like that, in Microsoft Access. There are things you can do, however:

1. Use the [shift bypass key](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-f19b5792-5a85-4516-89b2-43a10f60f1c1)

Using the bypass key will stop any code from automatically starting, allowing you to alter the database before it crashes

2. Using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>

Using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> stops the currently running code, and takes you to the VBA editor. However, if the application is not responding, it might not respond to <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>  either.

3. [Remove trust from the database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-database-objects-behave-when-trusted-and-untrusted-56e7b192-ae58-47df-8e4a-846dccf1caaf#bm2)

Using the security centre, you can untrust a database, blocking most code. This will allow you to access and copy database objects without code interfering.

4. Debug causes of database crashes (e.g. decompile)

[View this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897483/7296893) for a guide to debug causes of database crashes. Usually, decompiling does wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down *Shift* button(s) while you open the file.

Comment: it did not help(