# Access 2016 AppCrash when opening DB

Tags: ms-access, crash

I copied a split/compact&repaired DB from a system running Access 2013 to a new system running Access 2016.

I get an immediate crash if I attempt to open it.

If I temporarily rename the backend (so the frontend doesn't find it) then the front end opens OK.

I can then rename the backend to the correct name and the frontend can now access all my data. Everything works except a compact and repair. I have even recompiled all the VBA and that is fine too.

It will continue to work until I try and reopening it and then I'm forced to use my rename trick to get it going again.

The source DB both front and back were compacted/repaired before copying!

Any clues as to what I should check or look for?!?!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose MS access crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279330/how-to-diagnose-ms-access-crashes)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is database corruption. Create new database and copy all objects to new one, it may help. In most of cases coping doesn't fix corruption in tables data, export to xls and import may help in some cases.

Comment: I have already gone back to the original DB on the Access 2013 system and verified there is no corruption. I have now taken it to another Access 2013 system without issue.  I have subsequently repaired and corrected the original and taken that copy to the Access 2016 system but still the issue persists.  If the database is corrupt why is it only corrupt on Access 2016 systems?

Comment: There may be some problems during conversion. Try coping objects to new blank database, created in 2016, not conversion.

Comment: I have then exported all objects (minus data) on the Access 2013 system and imported them on the Access 2016 system all successfully.  But I cannot re-open the new DB after I close it.

Comment: How about opening the full 2013 version of your databse in MS Access 2016, check it for (VBA) culprits and then split it?

Comment: There is no full version. It has always been split.