# how do I know the actual cause of MS Access DB corruption

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have been through many articles talking about primary reasons about the MS Access DB corruption like :

- Hardware or software related issues.
- Multiple Users are accessing Database concurrently.
- The system is infected by Viruses / Worms.
- Faulty Access database design or structure.
- An inappropriate shutdown of the local machine

I would like to know if there's a way to determine the actual cause (like Network failure, multi-user access, incorrectly exited the DB etc.) of the DB corruption each time it happened by may be by looking at some logs or so.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is no such way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279330/how-to-diagnose-ms-access-crashes

Answer (score 0):

Your list can be reduced to:

- Network, disk, or OS related issues
- The system is infected by malware
- Access crashed
- An inappropriate shutdown of the local machine

But there is no log or similar to tell the actual cause.